# Find the last 5 results (ordered by eventdate) for each id in table

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql, excel

I need to find the last 5 results (ordered by eventdate) for each id from the test table

The table is structured in the example image below which is only showing the data from 1 id record of which there are thousands of different id's all with different results in time, hence why I only want the last 5 to be returned

[image]

I have the following query that is nearly correct but it is including num_result = 0 and auditflag=2 in the count of < 6 (which is of course down to my code being the novice that I am)

```
    SELECT q1.id, q1.eventdate, q1.num_result " _
      & "FROM test AS q1 INNER JOIN test AS q2 ON ( q1.id = q2.id ) " _
            & "AND ( q1.eventdate <= q2.eventdate ) AND q1.auditflag=1 " _
        & "WHERE q1.num_result > 0 " _
        & "GROUP BY q1.id, q1.eventdate, q1.num_result " _
        & "HAVING COUNT(*) < 6 " _
        & "ORDER BY q1.id, q1.eventdate DESC
```

I just want to find the last 5 records that match i.e. highlighted in yellow - Last 5 records from those with a num_result > 0 and auditflag=1

The SQL Query is written in Excel VBA connecting to a PG database using visoledb

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is basically your query:

```
SELECT q1.id, q1.eventdate, q1.num_result 
FROM test q1 INNER JOIN
     test q2
     ON q1.id = q2.id AND
        q1.eventdate <= q2.eventdate AND q1.auditflag = 1 
WHERE q1.num_result > 0
GROUP BY q1.id, q1.eventdate, q1.num_result 
ORDER BY q1.id, q1.eventdate DESC ;
```

I think you want this as your basic query:

```
SELECT q.id, q.eventdate,
       SUM( (q.auditflag = 1)::int) OVER (PARTITION BY q.id ORDER BY event_date) as num_result
FROM test q;
```

I think you want this with the filter:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT q.id, q.eventdate,
             SUM( (q.auditflag = 1)::int) OVER (PARTITION BY q.id ORDER BY event_date DESC) as num_result
     FROM test q
    ) q
WHERE num_result <= 5;
```

Comment: I getting an error message with both queries of "Translation error at line 1; Unexpected Symbol

Comment: @BradleyS . . . Does it point to any particular place in the query?  There is nothing obviously wrong that I can see.

Comment: It must be either VBA or the visoledb connection to PG that will not accept certain elements of the code to be used. Thank you for your help though, but I think I will have to try and use VBA to achieve this.

Comment: @BradleyS . . . Try using `cast()` instead of `::int`.  That is pretty non-standard and could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This type of query is typically solved with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), like:

```
SELECT   id, eventdate, num_result
FROM     (SELECT id, eventdate, num_result,
                 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY eventdate)
          FROM   test
          WHERE  num_result > 0
          AND    auditflag = 1) q
WHERE    row_number <= 5
ORDER BY id, eventdate DESC
```

But this will certainly cause a sequential scan on your whole table. In which (as you mentioned) there are thousands of rows per `id` and you need only the last 5 of them. This distribution is faster to query with [`LATERAL` subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```sql
SELECT    id, eventdate, num_result
FROM      (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test) q
          -- above use a table where "id" is a unique (primary) key
          -- f.ex. where "test.id" refers to if it's a foreign key
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT   eventdate, num_result
                   FROM     test
                   WHERE    id = q.id
                   AND      num_result > 0
                   AND      auditflag = 1
                   ORDER BY eventdate DESC
                   LIMIT    5) l ON TRUE
```

As for indexes, an `id, eventdate DESC` index on `test` would help a lot (also, you could make it a [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) one with `WHERE num_result > 0 AND auditflag = 1`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me in the end, although I had to use an identity field (which is global auditsequence and a unique record identifier). I had no knowledge of this until I asked why nothing was working, but hopefully the answer may help others. Thank you to all those that helped me with this.

```
select id, eventdate, num_result
from test
where test.identity IN
  (select top 5 identity from test as q1
  where q1.id=test.id and q1.auditflag=1 and q1.num_result>0 
  order by q1.eventdate desc)
order by id, eventdate desc
```